# ¿Cómo puedo borrar un grupo de celdas de manera rápida y que cumplan con una condición?

Tags: excel, vba, condiciones, formato-condicional, delete

Estoy usando el siguiente código en VBA para aplicaciones en Excel, pero es muy lento, porque los archivos tienen aproximadamente cien mil registros:

```
for Row= 1 to LastRow
   If sheet.cells(Row,1)<> "Y" then
      sheet.cells(Row,1).EntireRow.Delete
      Row=Row-1
   End if
next Row
```

¿Existe alguna manera de hacerlo más rápido?.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. ¿Has probado a filtrar en la primera columna por las que sean distinto a Y, y luego borrar todas las filas visibles? Mira acá, que te puede servir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410056/excel-vba-select-all-filtered-rows-except-header-after-autofilter

Answer (score 1):

Esa forma de hacerlo es inefectiva ya que digamos la fila 1 no contiene "Y" ni la 2 tampoco, al eliminar la fila 1, la fila 2 se convierte en fila 1 y tu bucle saltará a la fila 2 (anteriormente fila 3), así que se saltaría una.

Lo más eficiente es meter los datos en un array:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    Dim arr As Variant: arr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TUHOJA").UsedRange.Value
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 1) <> "Y" Then 'eliminamos las filas en las que la columna A no tiene la letra Y
            For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
                arr(i, j) = vbNullString
            Next j
        ElseIf arr(i - 1, 1) = vbNullString Then 'subimos datos si la fila anterior está vacía
            For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
                arr(i - 1, j) = arr(i, j)
                arr(i, j) = vbNullString
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TUHOJA").UsedRange.Value = arr
End Sub
```

Lo que tiene esto, es que si tu rango utilizado es mayor que el rango con datos, no parará hasta el final. Para evitar eso, pulsa ctrl+Fin y mira si en la fila de la celda a la que te salte tienes datos, si no los tienes, selecciona desde la primera fila sin datos hasta el final y las eliminas.

Answer (score 1):

Cien mil registros son muchos, no se que tan lento te va, pero es normal que toma algo de tiempo, ademas hay que considerar el poder de procesamiento de tu PC.

Hay que tomar en cuenta que cada vez que se elimina una fila, también se recalcula el libro, esto significa que si en ese libro hay muchas formulas, esto provocara que sea aun mas lento, sobre todo si se ejecuta muchas veces la parte donde se eliminan filas.

Para mejorar esto, lo que puedes hacer es agregar lo siguiente al inicio y final de tu código.

Al inicio.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Al final:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Esto elimina el parpadeo de pantalla y pospone el calculo de las formulas hasta que se termine el proceso de tu código.